# Selenium Web Driver Switch Context

Tags: selenium

I am quite new to Selenium Web driver and I suppose this is a basic question.
Anyway, I am having troubles in switching to a quick view window. Let me explain this with the image below

[image]

We got this by visiting amazon.com and hit "Quick look" on any item.
Now, suppose I want to click on the button "See product details",
how can I do this?

Do I have to accept the alert and then click? Like this java code for example

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
```

I tried this and does not work. 
How can handle situations like this? Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please post a HTML code of alert?

Answer (score 3):

"Quick look" modal window is not an alert. You just need to wait until it appeared in DOM. Try to add below code to your existed after you clicked "Quick look" button:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("See product details"))).click();
```

Comment: it did not worked with the linkText but did with xpath. I got the concep anyway. I was wrong because I've not considered it wasn't an alert.

Comment: It might not work with linkText in case your locale set not to English. You can also use `By.id("a-autoid-0-announce")` as well